# Fit background image to the whole screen no matter what size screen is

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a `<header class="header">` and inside this header tag I have the navagation bar. Basically I'm setting the background image through the `header` class so I can put the rest of the `<body>` content below the image. My layout of the page is:

```
<header class="header">
  <nav>
    navbar content
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  all the text and images are here in the body
</body>
```

And here is my css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The thing is that my background image fits perfectly and is responsive when I pull the website on my MacBook Air but when you pull up my website on a Mac desktop, the image doesn't fit the whole screen. I also have tried doing:

```
.header {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

But that didn't work. Is it possibly because of my image size? How do I make it so it fits the whole screen on ANY screen, including a large Mac desktop monitor?

Comment: image get stretch if you fit background image to the whole screen

Answer (score 3):

If percentage(%) is not working, you can use vh(view port height) and vw(view port width) to set background size

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url("https://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg");
    
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The background-image Property</h1>

<p>Hello World!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> the best way for setting a background-color is to add a div inside
>   body

```
<body>
     <div class='bg'></div>
</body>
```

> Now in css

```
.bg{
  background-image:url('../img/background.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%;
   z-index:-100;

 }
```